# How to play and pause MediaSession in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-music-player, android-mediasession

I'm trying to learn MediaSessions. I did a lot of research for music player which has MediaSession to learn how is it working. I found nothing about MediaSession. All music apps examples on youtube doesn't have MediaSession. I'm new in android and I did a music app but I didn't use MediaSession thefore I can't handle with headset keys, for example hook key . I really want to learn proper way to make an audio app.

Could you give a sample which is playing dummy audio with MediaSession and contains play and pause features please. All I need a sample Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Universal Android Music Player Sample](https://github.com/android/uamp) shows how to implement an audio media app that works across multiple form factors.

In the full guide, there's a [media session and controller section](https://github.com/android/uamp/blob/99e44c1c5106218c62eff552b64bbc12f1883a22/docs/FullGuide.md#the-media-session-and-controller) you'd probably like to read.

You can find MediaSession implemented in the UAMP sample [inside `MusicService`](https://github.com/android/uamp/blob/99e44c1c5106218c62eff552b64bbc12f1883a22/common/src/main/java/com/example/android/uamp/media/MusicService.kt#L180).

Other great resources:

- Our new [TV Reference App](https://github.com/android/tv-samples/tree/main/ReferenceAppKotlin) is tailored more towards video experiences on TV.
- See also my [codelab that steps through the basics of supporting MediaSessions](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/supporting-mediasession).

Comment: what you mean by "that works across multiple form factors"? What is a form factor?

Comment: As of this writing, UAMP supports Android mobile and [Android Automotive](https://source.android.com/devices/automotive/start/what_automotive).